# IIS Redirect Rule to redirect one url to another

Tags: redirect, iis

I Know this has been asked a lot but I just can't seem to figure out how to get this to work, even looking at other variables. 
I need to redirect www.example.com/article-2 to www.example.com/article

```html
                <rule name="Redirect Dup Artivcle URL" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=" https://www.example.com/article-2/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/article/" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
```

I feel like I may have the wrong URL matching pattern...

Comment: Learn how to debug first, and then nothing can stop you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

Its obviously that {HTTP_HOST} is not covering https://.
Please modify the rule like this

```
            <rule name="Redirect Dup Artivcle URL" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.example.com/article-2/" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/article/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
```

[image]